# SendGrid + Ruby on Rails 6 on DigitalOcean Apps + Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, digital-ocean, sendgrid, econnrefused

I believe this error is about ENV API Key. This works fine on my localhost but on server.

I added my API key to
Components / Environment Variables:
[image]

and my development.rb file. as below:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    :port           => "587",
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => 'apikey',
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY']
  }
```

And I still get the error as below

**Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25):**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARGH! Wasted 2 days on this. All I have to do was adding the Actionmailer settings to

**production.rb**

I had it only in development.rb file before. Duh!!